summation of a few harmonic series
How to show that $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(4n-1\right)\left(4n-2\right)\left(4n-3\right)} =\frac{\ln\left(2\right)}{4} ?$$
Breaking the general term into partial fractions was relatively easy:
$$=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{2\left(4n-1\right)}-\frac{1}{4n-2}+\frac{1}{2\left(4n-3\right)}$$
First of all, I hoped it to be a telescoping series and wrote down few terms:
$$\left(\frac{1}{6}-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{2}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{14}-\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{10}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{22}-\frac{1}{10}+\frac{1}{18}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{30}-\frac{1}{14}+\frac{1}{26}\right)+\left(\frac{1}{38}-\frac{1}{18}+\frac{1}{34}\right)\cdots$$
But, it doesn't seem to telescope. The terms do not cancel each other in a symmetric way.
Now, I had no idea on how to proceed, so I looked on stack exchange and found a bunch of methods but most of them used integration and some special series which I am unaware of and probably not supposed to use.
Further I went backwards and tried forming the series off ln(2) expansion (manipulation of original series to form something like 4*ln(2)):
$$\ln\left(2\right)=\ln\left(1+1\right)=1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}\cdots$$
But it came of no use to me. Any help would be appreciated.

Hi, welcome to Math SE. Hint: use $\frac{1}{4n-i}=\int_0^1x^{4n-i-1}dx$.

@J.G. Thanks for the hint! However, I am looking for ways that do not involve integration.

You found the two relevant ingredients! (partial fractions and alternating harmonic series)
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2(4n-1)}+\frac1{2(4n-3)}-\frac1{2(4n-2)}-\frac1{8n}\right)=-\frac12\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k$$
and
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(-\frac1{2(4n-2)}+\frac1{8n}\right)=\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k$$
hence
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{\left(4n-1\right)\left(4n-2\right)\left(4n-3\right)}$$$$=\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac1{2(4n-1)}+\frac1{2(4n-3)}-\frac1{4n-2}\right)=-\frac14\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}k=\frac{\ln2}4.$$

I must say, that is a really creative and intuitive approach to the problem. Thanks for this beautiful solution!
